# Sumif Formula with no duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to have sumif formula which avoid duplicates.  For example if something has been summed in the above rows, I don’t want it to be summed again if it’s down in the below rows, can you please assist?

```
=SUMIF($R$50:$R$54,R50,$AG$50:$AG$54)
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "Has been summed in the above rows"? Maybe it should read "Sumif only unique values"?

Comment: thats it . only sum unique values

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to add another column for additional criteria?

For example, if you add another column (let's say it's in column A) with the formula

`=IF(COUNTIF($R$50:R50,R50)=1,1,0)`

The formula above will return a 1 if the value in Cell R50 is unique, and a 0 if it is not. Now change your SumIf function to SumIfs. You could use

`=SUMIFS($AG$50:$AG$54,$R$50:$R$54,R50,$A$50:$A$54,1)`

to return the sum of only unique values.

The SumIfs function is pretty much a SumIf function, but with the ability to use multiple criteria without the need for an array function. SumIf criteria is `SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)`, so we are returning the sum of all values in AG50:AG54 where the value in R50:R54 matches that of R50 AND the unique flag in A50:A54 equals 1.

**Edit**
I should clarify that the SUMIFS formula isn't available in Office 2003 and below. If this means you cannot use SUMIFS, I believe you will need an array formula, let me know.

Comment: is the 1 offsetting?

Comment: Apologies no, I'll edit the answer and explain the formula

Comment: this is the range i am working with =SUMIF($Q$83:$Q168,Q83,$AG$82:$AG$168)

Comment: Although this isn't what you posted in your question, I don't see the problem as the basic premise is that same. Just modify the SUMIFS formula to suit your data ranges

Comment: in coloumn Q83 - Q168 has names and in coloumn ag82-ag168 there are scores. so i was hoping to only sum a person once.

Comment: I think we are talking cross purposes, do you want the total of all the scores from unique names only, or do you want to get the score of a specific person in a list?

Comment: `=SUMIF($A$82:$A$168,1,$AG$82:$AG$168) `

Comment: Have you added the countif function in column A?

Comment: what i aiming for is a subtotal of each person

Comment: Then I refer you to the answer I posted an hour ago, I can't help you any further

Comment: =IF($R84=$R83,"",SUMIFS($AG:$AG,$R:$R,$R84,$S:$S,$S84))

Comment: Is this a joke? Where did column S come from?

Comment: Apologies what I did is that I'move the columns.  I'm still trying to implement yours

Comment: @AranDG Well done, I got this to work for my issue!

Comment: @ACohen Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF($R84=$R83,"",SUMIFS($AG:$AG,$R:$R,$R84,$S:$S,$S84))
```